# Script help rename - copy - move

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a PowerShell script to do the following.

1. Rename files in source (FTP folders) directories with it's "current_name_datetime.csv" as per a source file "Source_list.csv" this file has the directories "source,destination" I want this script to look into.
2. Copy newly renamed files to backup directories as per destination in Source_list.csv this file has the directories "source,destination" I want this script to look into.
3. Move newly renamed files to final destination directory which is not in my current script.

Source_list.csv contents

cscenter,Costume_Supercenter

fkimports,FKImports

My Script:

```psh
$sdfiles = Get-Content c:\!tony\Source_list.csv
$sourceDir = "c:\test\"
$destinationDir = "c:\testing\"

Get-ChildItem $sourceDir -Recurse -Include $sdfiles "*.csv"|
ForEach-Object{
       $newname= "{0}{1}_{2}.csv" -f $destinationDir, $_.BaseName,     [datetime]::Now.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy-hh-mm-ss')
    $_|Copy-Item -Include ,$sdfiles -Destination $newname -whatif }
```

Error:

```
What if: Performing operation "Copy Directory" on Target "Item: C:\test\cscenter Destination: C:\testing\cscenter_10-01-2015-12-22-24.csv".
```

I see in the error that it is trying to copy the directory not the single file in each directory and creating a new folder using the original folder name and renaming the folder and appending the date/time stamp.

Comment: Can we see what a couple of lines in `Source_list.csv` look like?

Comment: Also whatever `$sfiles` is. Unless that is a typo then that would be an issue.

Comment: Source_list.csv   cscenter,Costume_Supercenter
fkimports,FKImports

Comment: $sfiles should be sdfiles

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32894170/edit) the question with these details so I can see the structure better

Comment: Post has been edited.

Comment: Hey Matt, any idea on what I could be doing wrong? I very new to powershell and would greatly appreciate any advice you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Confused. The `-Include` parameter should only be accepting a single array of strings, throwing `"*.csv"` on to the end of it won't work AFAIK. Additionally It will be interpreting the whole line of the CSV, ie searching for the file "cscenter,Costume_Supercenter" so shouldn't be returning anything. At least that's what I see when I replicate this on my computer.

Lastly you've tried to filter the files, piped that to Copy-Item and tried to filter it again?

I'd take a more straightforward approach:

```
$sdfiles = Import-CSV c:\!tony\Source_list.csv -Header @("File", "Folder")

$sourcedir = "c:\test\"
$destinationdir = "c:\testing\"

$sdfiles | ForEach-Object {
    $path = $sourcedir + $_.File + ".csv"
    $folder = $destinationdir + $_.Folder + '\'
    if (!(Test-Path $folder)) { New-Item -Type Directory -Path $folder }
    if (Test-Path ($path))
    {
        $newname = "{0}{1}_{2}.csv" -f $folder, $_.File, (Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy-hh-mm-ss')
        Copy-Item -Path $path -Destination $newname -whatif
    }
    else { Write-Error "File $($_.File) not found" }
}
```

It's a bit chunkier but much easier to read and tweak to your liking. Note that Import-CSV does require PowerShell v3. Let me know if you've got v2 and need help tweaking it for a two-dimensional array.

I also recommend looking into Microsoft's MVA courses on PowerShell, they are excellent resources for starting out.

Comment: the script above also cannot find *.csv files to rename, i'm using PS v3. also.

Comment: File FKImports\*.csv; FKImports not found
At C:\Users\TONY\Desktop\PowerShell\File_copy_Rev22.ps1:6 char:27
+ $sdfiles | ForEach-Object {
+                           ~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException

Comment: Weird place for the error to pop up but I think this may be because the directory doesn't exist? I assumed you wanted your backup directory set to `C:\Testing\[2nd column]` but tweak to your liking. I've added another line, try again.

Comment: Hi Deadly-Bagel, the update now copies the folder structure to but not the files, the folder structure is already there however so no need to reproduce it. its the coping of the files that is in error
File COSTSS_*.csv not found
At line:24 char:28
+  $sdfiles | ForEach-Object {
+                            ~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException

Comment: It would seem that this task cannot be completed in a few lines of code , I think the files need to be renamed  in their current directory then copied to back up folder and finally moved to the end location.

Comment: I've tested the above extensively and found no issues, it does exactly what you want. Get names from a spreadsheet, find those files, rename them and move them to a folder. Are the files called exactly the names in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Waaaaaaiiiiit - looking at your error again... Looks like the source_list file contains `FKImports*.csv; FKImports`, is that correct? Please be exact.